# What is a simple software to log how much time is taken to complete a task?

Tags: project-management, time-management

I tried googling for the software also searched on Google Play store, but the results I am getting are complex software about team management or Gnatt charts which look complex to use. I googled '**project management**', '**time management**', '**project planner**' etc, but I am not getting what I want. I don't want to collaborate with teams, I just want to see how much time I am taking for programming tasks at hand. Something [like this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27186/71041) but much simpler.

I am looking for **software or a website or an android app** where I can create a task say for e.g.

> complete the code from client X

and then until I complete the task I should see in the program that the task is incomplete and when the task is complete I should have the function to mark it as complete. **The software should then show me how much time or days was spent doing that task.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm intimately familiar with an app called [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) - it does pretty much exactly what you ask, it tracks the apps you have open and are actively using on your computer, and gives you reports as to how much time you spent doing what.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am looking for something similar, but it should be manual, as I am not working on the same computer all day, I have a Linux machine and a Windows machine, and for me completing the task requires working on both...so I don't want an automatic activity checker...

Comment: If you want something more manual, there's also [TaskWarrior](https://taskwarrior.org) - one command to start tracking on a given task and another to stop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a simple, manual time-tracking app, I created [Timekeeper](https://github.com/skauertz/Timekeeper) which may be interesting for you.

It does not have the ability to mark a task as "Done" (although I think that could be added), but otherwise would do what you need I think, and it works on Linux and Windows.